# jQuery Auto Refresh Send Value Variable

Tags: jquery

I want to pass value of variable using jQuery Auto refresh like this :

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval
(
function ()
{
var p_box_sn = $("#p_box_sn").val();

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#counts').load('load.php?p_box_sn=p_box_sn').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000
);
```

But it show output : p_box_sn.
What I wanted is to get value from var p_box_sn and sent it to load function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `p_box_sn` is a variable, you need to concatenate it using `+`:

```
$('#counts').load('load.php?p_box_sn=' + p_box_sn).fadeIn("slow");
```